# x64-windows and CMAKE_C_COMPILER CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER

Tags: cmake

I am building yolov3 darknet repository. Dependencies are CMAKE, CUDA. I am getting error in CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER.

Error is as below:

```
Error: Building package pthreads:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: pthreads:x64-windows
  Vcpkg version: 2021-09-10-2059ef11aa6067e6f59b0d939c5d17e3c5c47d3e

Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.
-- Running vcpkg install - failed
CMake Error at vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:829 (message):
  vcpkg install failed.  See logs for more information:
  C:\Users\HP\Documents\Yolo1\darknet\build_release\vcpkg-manifest-install.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:124 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:103 (project)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Config failed! Exited with error code 1.
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: In addition to the problem mentioned, cmake also doesn't seem to be able to find the Ninja build tool. You may need to install that too, unless you've got the option to use something else.

Comment: I have installed Ninja too and added that in PATH variable. "Using Ninja from C:\Program Files\Ninja\ninja.exe
Ninja version 1.10.2"    I got this in the log file. Program is able to get the CMAKE and Ninja from the PATH in the environmental variable but still getting this error.